# Azure Dev ops Release deployment failed due to 'Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger' error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-deployment

'Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

PowerShell exited with code '1'.

all the az modules have been installed despite of that I am getting this error

Comment: Which version of powershell you are using ? Meanwhile you can refer this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f2053dc6-ed1a-4d5a-bcbc-91e5404fde9f/the-term-getazdatafactoryv2trigger-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet?forum=AzureDataFactory

Comment: Can you share the PowerShell version you are using and the script as well ?

Comment: PSVersion                      5.1.14393.4583  @NadineRaiss

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your PowerShell version. Take a look a the documentation for the [Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/get-azdatafactoryv2trigger?view=azps-6.5.0) function.

[image: Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger]

Here is the PowerShell task where you can use the latest version:

```
 - task: AzurePowerShell@4
   displayName: 'Execute script'
   inputs:
     azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.azConnection }}'
     ScriptType: InlineScript
     Inline: |     
       ##code
     azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```